# Deleting rows that don't end in a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to delete all the rows in the dataframe that don't contain an hour string e.g. 00:00, 13:00 09:00 etc. I'm trying to say that if the string in the timestamp column doesn't end in ":00" then drop the row. my code so far seems to be deleting every row. Any ideas?

```
    timestamp   date    activity    Id  total hour activity
720 00:00   2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
721 00:01   2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
722 00:02   2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
723 00:03   2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
724 00:04   2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
10794   23:54   2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10795   23:55   2003-05-14  12  condition_1 NaN
10796   23:56   2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10797   23:57   2003-05-14  18  condition_1 NaN
10798   23:58   2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN

badTimes = df[df['timestamp'].str.endswith(":00") == False]
newdf = df.drop(badTimes, axis= 1)
newdf
```

Comment: Just `badTimes = df[df['timestamp'].str.endswith(":00") == False]` would be what's you are looking for. Actually, `goodTimes = df[df['timestamp'].str.endswith(":00") ]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
goodTimes = df[df['timestamp'].str.endswith(":00")]
df = goodTimes
df
```